# Balancing ragged right line lengths

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I have a `\section`-like command that takes an optional title. The title may be empty (default), short or so long that it doesn't fit on one line. In the latter case, I would like it to be split into lines of about equal length and printed `\raggedright`. Is this possible?

I found other questions where the approach is to reduce the glue added at the end of each line, but I don't think I can go that route since the title may be empty and I would need the glue to stretch over the whole line in that case.

---

Here's a toy version of my command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \par
  {\raggedright\Large\bfseries\sffamily
    \strut #1%
    \par
  }%
  \hrule
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
asdf

\foo{}
asdf

\foo{short}
asdf

\foo{long, I mean really long, so long that it can't fit on a single line}
asdf

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

Desired output:
[image: MWE output]

Comment: (Not tested.)  Set the title in a box, and determine if the width exceeds the default text width.  If it does, try using a `parbox` that's (say) .6 times the width of the measured line.  Some iteration may be needed to determine an "ideal" length.

Comment: you could set it first in an hbox, measure the natural length decide how many lines are needs and then set in a parbox of a suitable width, but to be honest I wouldn't I would just use `\\ ` to add line breaks by hand, choosing good breaks for the heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compute the natural width of the text and then set `\rightskip` to the line width minus an approximate width for the lines to typeset, with some stretchability.

Also applying a rather high value for `\linepenalty`, we keep the number of lines at the minimum.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\fooformat}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}

\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \par
  \sbox0{\fooformat #1}%
  {%
   \raggedright
   \fooformat
   \linepenalty3000
   \rightskip=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0/\fpeval{1+round(\wd0/\textwidth)}\relax plus 4em\relax
   \strut #1\par
  }%
  \hrule
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
asdf

\foo{}
asdf

\foo{short}
asdf

\foo{long, I mean really long, so long that it can't fit on a single line}
asdf

\foo{long, I mean really long, so long that it can't fit on a single line
 and even longer, but really really longer}
asdf

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I allowed my `\rightskip` to shrink to zero, which avoids additional problems (in my tests, changing `\lineskip` wasn't necessary with this change).